# How to fix "Circular reference" error on YAML file?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

> FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException: Circular reference
>   detected in "/app/config/routing_dev.yml"
>   ("/app/config/routing_dev.yml" >
>   "/app/config/routing.yml" > "." >
>   "@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Controller/" > 
>   "/app/config/routing_dev.yml").

I'm trying to achieve this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html#more-advanced-loaders

so I created this file

AdvancedLoader.php

```
<?php
//namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Routing;
namespace Gabriel\AdminPanelBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class AdvancedLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();

        $resource = '@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml';
        $type = 'yaml';

        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource, $type);

        $collection->addCollection($importedRoutes);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return $type === 'advanced_extra';
    }
}
```

/src/Gabriel/AdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    gabriel.routing_loader:
        class: Gabriel\AdminPanelBundle\Routing\AdvancedLoader
        tags:
            - { name: routing.loader }
```

/app/config/routing.yml

```
gabriel_messaging:
    resource: "@GabrielMessagingBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

# app/config/routing.yml
Gabriel_Extra:
    resource: .
    type: advanced_extra
```

app/config/routing_dev.yml

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

/src/Gabriel/AdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
gabriel_admin_panel:
    resource: "@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Controller/"
    type:     advanced_extra
    prefix:   /superuser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at `@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`:

```
gabriel_admin_panel:
    resource: "@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Controller/"
    type:     advanced_extra
    prefix:   /superuser
```

The `type` specifies which loader should be used, in this case you said `advanced_extra`, which is your loader. Your loader includes this file again and the file will execute the loader again, this will continue forever (in other words: a circular reference).

---

Please also note that you already included the routes in `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
gabriel_messaging:
    resource: "@GabrielMessagingBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

This time, you use the correct type: `annotation`. You should remove this entry and edit the `@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` file to use correct types.

Comment: Quote: "A custom route loader allows you to add routes to an application without including them, for example, in a YAML file. This comes in handy when you have a bundle but don't want to manually add the routes for the bundle to app/config/routing.yml. This may be especially important when you want to make the bundle reusable."

Comment: Yeah, but know you add the routes to routing.yml and let a router import thr same file again

Comment: I moved the configuration of the AdminPanelBundle into a routing.yml file that's within the bundle, please check the last file I included

Comment: sorry, I completely misread your question. I've edited my answer